# Aggregate by repeated values in a column in a data frame in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame as follows:

```
             value     identifier
2007-01-01  0.781611      55
2007-01-01  0.766152      56
2007-01-01  0.766152      57
2007-02-01  0.705615      55
2007-02-01  0.032134      56
2007-02-01  0.032134      57
2008-01-01  0.026512      55
2008-01-01  0.993124      56
2008-01-01  0.993124      57
2008-02-01  0.226420      55
2008-02-01  0.033860      56
2008-02-01  0.033860      57
```

How can I aggregate by the value in the identifier column, like this:

```
           value  
2007-01-01  0.766  # (average of identifiers 55, 56 and 57 for this date)
2007-02-01  0.25   
2008-01-01  etc... 
2008-02-01
```

Comment: One question at a time please, you should ask another question rather than increment the scope of this one, basically it can be done but it's a little weird, could you try this: `g = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby(df.index.date)['value'].mean())
g.index = pd.to_datetime(g.index)
month_value = g.groupby([g.index.year, g.index.month])['value'].mean()`

Comment: Thanks, removed the second question. Gonna put in another one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your index is a datetime then you can access the `.date` attribute, if not you can convert it using `df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)` and then perform a groupby on the date and calc the mean:

```
In [214]:

df.groupby(df.index.date)['value'].mean()
Out[214]:
2007-01-01    0.771305
2007-02-01    0.256628
2008-01-01    0.670920
2008-02-01    0.098047
Name: value, dtype: float64
```

Comment: If the index is of type `pd.Timestamp`, you don't need to add the `.date` parameter.

Comment: It is datetime, do I still need to add it?