# Aggregate by repeated datetime index with different identifiers in a column on a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame in this form:

```
         value     identifier
2007-01-01  0.781611      55
2007-01-01  0.766152      56
2007-01-01  0.766152      57
2007-02-01  0.705615      55
2007-02-01  0.032134      56
2007-02-01  0.032134      57
2008-01-01  0.026512      55
2008-01-01  0.993124      56
2008-01-01  0.993124      57
2008-02-01  0.226420      55
2008-02-01  0.033860      56
2008-02-01  0.033860      57
```

I can group the data by identifier using this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29701242/aggregate-by-repeated-values-in-a-column-in-a-data-frame-in-pandas).

```
by_date = df.groupby(df.index.date)['value'].mean()
2007-01-01    0.771305
2007-02-01    0.256628
2008-01-01    0.670920
2008-02-01    0.098047
```

Now I want to do a boxplot by month, so I would imagine that I can group by it:

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame()
new_df['value'] = by_date
by_month = by_date.groupby(by_date.index.month)
aa = by_month.groupby(lambda x: x.month)
aa.boxplot(subplots=False)
```

How can I create this boxplot without the dummy dataframe?

Comment: This is a subtle one could you try this: `by_date = df.groupby(df.index.date)[['value']].mean()` this will return a df which means you don't need to create a dummy df, by double subscripting you return a df with a single column rather than a series

Comment: Wow, thanks. Could you please point to the docs or the code about why this works?

Comment: I can't seem to find it, but if you consider that passing a list of col names to this `df[col_list]` this is no different to `df[[col_a, col_b]]` which is sematically different to `df[col_a]` but analagous to `df[[col_a]]`, there is this [section](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html#indexing-selection) but it's not spelt out

Comment: Thanks. Do you mind putting in form of a answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for the groupby to return a df instead of a Series then use double subsription `[[]]`:

```
by_date = df.groupby(df.index.date)[['value']].mean()
```

this then allows you to groupby by month and generate a boxplot:

```
by_month = by_date.groupby(by_date.index.month)
by_month.boxplot(subplots=False)
```

The use of double subsription is a subtle feature which is not immediately obvious, generally doing `df[col]` will return a column, but we know that passing a list of columns `col_list` will return a df: `df[col_list]` which when expanded is the same as `df[[col_a, col_b]]` this then leads to the conclusion that we can return a df if we did the following: `df[[col_a]]` as we've passed a list with a single element, this is not the same as `df[col_a]` where we've passed a label to perform column indexing.

Comment: Great answer, thanks. Very subtle point indeed, and it seems that this could be an enhancement to pandas, as I've been using the dummy dataframe a lot.

Comment: Another one that catches people out is say why does `df.groupby(col)['col_a','col_b']` raise a KeyError and it's because this is syntactic sugar for `df['col_a','col_b'].groupby(col)` now it's clear why this fails there is no col labeled `'col_a', 'col_b'` but if we did this then it would work: `df.groupby(col)[['col_a','col_b']]`

Comment: The interesting part is that after the first groupby ([[ ]]) and mean, the index is not datetime anymore, but instead object. I have to cast again using to_datetime to be able to do the second groupby.

Comment: Yes this I think is possibly a bug which is a little surprising

Answer (score 1):

When you did the groupby on date, you converted the index from a Timestamp to a datetime.date.

```
>>> type(df.index[0])
pandas.tslib.Timestamp

>>> type(by_date.index[0])
datetime.date
```

If you convert the index to Periods, you can groupby easily.

```
df.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(by_date.index).to_period('M')
>>> df.groupby(df.index).value.sum()
2007-01-01    2.313915
2007-02-01    0.769883
2008-01-01    2.012760
2008-02-01    0.294140
Name: value, dtype: float64
```