# Average of aggregated value by month and boxplot average differs on pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data set as follows:

```
     value     identifier
2007-01-01  0.781611      55
2007-01-01  0.766152      56
2007-01-01  0.766152      57
2007-02-01  0.705615      55
2007-02-01  0.032134      56
2007-02-01  0.032134      57
2008-01-01  0.026512      55
2008-01-01  0.993124      56
2008-01-01  0.993124      57
2008-02-01  0.226420      55
2008-02-01  0.033860      56
2008-02-01  0.033860      57
```

After a sequence of questions and very helpful [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29702372/aggregate-by-repeated-datetime-index-with-different-identifiers-in-a-column-on-a/29702872?noredirect=1#comment47548294_29702872), I came up with this:

```
group = df.groupby(df.index)[['value']].mean()
group.index = pd.to_datetime(group.index) # probably a bug
group_month = group.groupby(group.index.month)
group_month.mean().plot()
```

So I have a line graph with the mean values per month. Now I want to generate a boxplot, so I use this:

```
ax = group_month.boxplot(subplots=False)
```

And with the boxplots, the averages  <strike>(the bars in the middle of the boxplots) are different from the previous graph. I this expected? (I can't post graphs right now and it seems that the example dataset is ok, but I have a larger data set that is in the exactly same format that is giving me trouble).</strike>  Boxplots provide the median, not the mean.

Comment: Box plots use the median, not the mean.

Comment: My fault! Could you please point to the pandas docs bout this?

Comment: It's not a Pandas specific feature. Most box plots use the median. There's a description of the plot [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Box-and-WhiskerPlot.html). The Pandas [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.boxplot.html#pandas.DataFrame.boxplot) does mention that the median is used, although it doesn't describe that it is the central line.